# Root file system in Mint MATE

Tags: linux-mint, filesystems

I am relatively new to Linux (read: tedious noob question), but now that I switched to Mint MATE, I have a question regarding the structure of the file system here (perhaps, even more generally in Linux).

My understanding was that the top of the file system tree was the root with all other dirs/files as children. Now, what I'm seeing here is a "Computer" directory with a couple of files (a DVDRAM and what seems to be the HDD of the laptop) alongside the root file system in it. My thinking was that perhaps these are just devices that are actually under /dev, but that were placed here for one reason or another in this distro. However, I don't seem to be able to navigate there through the terminal and can't find anything similar under root. Could you elaborate on what these files might represent exactly and what their placement is in relation to the root file system?

(I understand this may involve covering some OS basics, so feel free to redirect me elsewhere)

Answer (score 2):

Every file manager (`caja`, `nemo`, `nautilus`, etc) has its own way of arranging and showing places and devices.

"Computer" is not a directory but a category used by `caja` to sort such things.

A place is a path that stems from the root directory `/`.

A device can be shown in the file manager *but not mounted*. When you click on it it will mount in some path, which now you can access. Usually in Ubuntu's derivatives it will be something like `/media/user/DEVICE`.

When you wan to see the actual directory you are in, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, the address bar will show you the actual path.

[More information about the Linux file system structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).